# Custom comparator for Swift

Tags: swift

This is my code (simplified code):

```
struct SomeStruct {
    let id: Int
    let age: Int
}

extension SomeStruct: Hashable {
    var hashValue: Int {
        return id.hashValue * age.hashValue
    }

    static func ==(lhs: SomeStruct, rhs: SomeStruct) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id && lhs.age == rhs.age
    }
}

struct Calculator {
    let struct1: [SomeStruct]
    let struct2: [SomeStruct]

    func uniqueById() {
        let struct3 = Set(struct2).union(Set(struct1))

        // I want to union it by property 'id' only.
        // If the property 'id' is equal for both objects,
        // the object in struct2 should be used (since that can have a different age property)
    }
}
```

`SomeStruct` is a generated `struct` **which I do not want to edit**. I want to create a `Set` for `SomeStruct` that is based on 1 property: `id`. For that, I think I need a custom `Comparator`, [just as Java has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245093/how-do-i-use-comparator-to-define-a-custom-sort-order). Is there any Swifty way? This is the only thing I can come up with, but I am wondering if there is a better way:

```
struct SomeStructComparatorById: Hashable {
    let someStruct: SomeStruct

    var hashValue: Int {
        return someStruct.id.hashValue
    }

    static func ==(lhs: SomeStructComparatorById, rhs: SomeStructComparatorById) -> Bool {
        return lhs.someStruct.id == rhs.someStruct.id
    }
}
```

Comment: @matt if my way of doing it is correct. I was searching for an initializer for a Set that takes a custom Comparator or something, but I couldn't find it. Is this the best/recommended way? Or is there some protocol I should use?

Comment: Should `Set(struct2)` have elements unique only by `id`? (The `hashValue` will be eliminating some)

Comment: @Carpsen90 Yes, I want say: SomeStruct is unique by id, not by the combination of id AND age. Since SomeStruct is generated, I don't want to edit it, and it has a default implementation of Hashable...

Comment: The approach from https://stackoverflow.com/q/42542035/1187415 would also work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I don't think this would work in Java. `addAll()` doesn't take a Comparator (nor does `contains`, etc.) Comparators are for sorting, not equality. Conceptually this is breaking how Set works in any language. Two items are not "equal" unless they can be swapped in all cases.

That tells us that we don't want a Set here.  What you want here is uniqueness based on some key. That's a Dictionary (as Daniel discusses).

You could either just have a "id -> age" dictionary or "id -> struct-of-other-properties" dictionary as your primary data type (rather than using Array). Or you can turn your Array into a temporary Dictionary like this:

```
extension Dictionary {
    init<S>(_ values: S, uniquelyKeyedBy keyPath: KeyPath<S.Element, Key>)
        where S : Sequence, S.Element == Value {
        let keys = values.map { $0[keyPath: keyPath] }
        self.init(uniqueKeysWithValues: zip(keys, values))
    }
}
```

And merge them like this:

```
let dict1 = Dictionary(struct1, uniquelyKeyedBy: \.id)
let dict2 = Dictionary(struct2, uniquelyKeyedBy: \.id)
let merged = dict1.merging(dict2, uniquingKeysWith: { old, new in old }).values
```

This leaves `merged` as `[SomeStruct]`.

Note that this `Dictionary(uniquelyKeyedBy:)` has the same preconditions as `Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:)`. If there are duplicate keys, it's a programming error and will raise precondition failure.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no. Swift sets do not have any way to accept a custom comparator and if you absolutely must have a Set, then your wrapper idea is the only way to do it. I question the requirement for a set though.

Instead of using Set in your calculator, I recommend using dictionary.

You can use a Dictionary to produce an array where each item has a unique ID...

```
let struct3 = Dictionary(grouping: struct1 + struct2, by: { $0.id })
        .compactMap { $0.value.max(by: { $0.age < $1.age })}
```

Or you can keep the elements in a [Int: SomeStruct] dictionary:

```
let keysAndValues = (struct1 + struct2).map { ($0.id, $0) }
let dictionary = Dictionary(keysAndValues, uniquingKeysWith: { lhs, rhs in 
    lhs.age > rhs.age ? lhs : rhs 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
var setOfIds: Set<Int> = []
var struct3 = struct2.filter { setOfIds.insert($0.id).inserted }
struct3 += struct1.filter { setOfIds.insert($0.id).inserted }
```

The result would be an array of `SomeStruct`, with all elements with unique `id`s.

You could define this as a custom operator :

```
infix operator *>

func *> (lhs: [SomeStruct], rhs: [SomeStruct]) -> [SomeStruct] {
    var setOfIds: Set<Int> = []
    var union = lhs.filter { setOfIds.insert($0.id).inserted }
    union += rhs.filter { setOfIds.insert($0.id).inserted }
    return union
}
```

Your code would then look like this:

```
func uniqueById() {
    let struct3 = struct2 *> struct1
    //use struct3
}
```